# CompactLayout REST API returning only Primary Layout

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, compact-layout

I am using Metadata REST API to call all the compactLayout 
`/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/sobject__c/describe/compactLayout`

But it is returning only 1 compactLayout not all.
There is one more API which just returns the Primary Layout
`/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/sobject__c/describe/compactLayout/primary/`

both are giving me the same response. 
Anyone has used or faced similar kind of situation?
Please help me

Comment: Rest Api will only give layout that is assigned to you Even if there are multiple Compact layouts.

Comment: Is there anyway where I can get all the compact Layouts.
@ManjotSingh Thanks for reply